# Setting attributes by attribute name in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I've got this somewhat ugly code writing to a bunch of properties. It seems I should be able to loop through a list to do this.  How would I loop through `['command','options','library']` and set the associated property?

```
    <snip>

    try:
        self.command = data_dict['command']
    except KeyError:
        pass

    try:
        self.options = data_dict['options']
    except KeyError:
        pass

    try:
        self.library = data_dict['library']
    except KeyError:
        pass

   <snip>
```

Comment: Would the `getattr` function suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
for name in ['command', 'options', 'library']:
    try:
        value = data_dict[name]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        setattr(self, name, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) to set an attribute with a dynamic name.

In my opinion it is cleaner check if the key exists rather than handling the `KeyError`.

```
for name in ['command', 'options', 'library']:
    if name in data_dict:
        setattr(self, name, value)
```